# What kind of object is こんだら?

Tags: song-lyrics

I was listening the the opening theme of the animation 巨人の星. I was able to pick up the first part.

```
重いこんだら
```

I understand that `重い` (heavy) is a relative clause modifying `こんだら`. What is こんだら? It should be something heavy, I guess. Is it related to コンドル? Or, is it a type of ゴンドラ?

Comment: It's 思いこんだら (not 重いこんだら) according to several websites (e.g. [Mojim](http://mojim.com/twy116069x1x1.htm)), which I think is the たら form of 思い込む.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of that song, 「思い込む」 does not mean "to be convinced".

> It means along the line of "to make a firm resolution".

Answer (score 9):

コンダラ is a slangy word for a man-powered "land roller" to flatten the grounds, like this one.

[image: Kondara]

Although the "correct" name of this tool is "(整地【せいち】)ローラー" or something, there are a few high school students who actually call this コンダラ. Even Japanese Wikipedia has the [entry for コンダラ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%A9).

---

Yes, I'm only half kidding. What is really said in that song is "思い込んだら" (=*if (you are) determined*), not "重いコンダラ".

But you are not the only person who misinterpreted it as 重いコンダラ.

Actually there were great many native Japanese people who heard that song and wondered, "What's コンダラ? It must be something heavy, used by little leaguers? Oh I got it, it's the name of that roller!"

This error became a very famous joke, repeated on the radio and TV many times in the past. And  some people actually started to call this コンダラ. And now, at last, there are people who call this just コンダラ and don't know why it's コンダラ!

You can show the picture above and ask "what's the name of this?", and I'm sure many people will answer "definitely it's コンダラ", jokingly or seriously. The following is a real question made by a native Japanese speaker who wanted to know the etymology of コンダラ.

運動場を平らにする時に使う大きなローラーをコンダラと言ってましたが、何語なのか、さっぱり分かりません。一応色んな言葉の辞書は見ました。
http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1256308673

And you can read the article [コンダラ](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%A9) in pixiv百科事典, which describes this word rather seriously.

---

**Edit**: Putting the joke aside, 「思い込む」 here may be a bit confusing. In this context, 「思い込む」 means "strongly determine (one's way of living)", not "one's (erroneous) assumption".

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is spelled in katakana if it is a made-up word?

Comment: Because it's not a Japanese-origin device. And incidentally, コンダラ sounds like English words, something like *condallar*.

Comment: Where is the answer to the question?

Comment: Where in the question did OP ask the meaning of 思い込む? :) (just kidding... you've answered it already)

Answer (score 1):

思【おも】い込【こ】む
means to be convinced of something

日本語が難しいと思い込んでいる
I'm convinced that Japanese is difficult (whether that's actually true or not).

思い込む　→　連用形　+　～たら(if / when)　→　思い込んだら

Comment: The meaning "convinced" does not seem to fit in this case. The lyrics continues: "おもいこんだらしれんのみちお". Could there be another meaning?

Comment: Even that really isn't enough to do much with. How about more complete lyrics then? At least the phrase before and after.

Comment: As you now know 思い込む has two meanings and you have given the other one but tx it might help me remember both. (BTW Good example of the other: 思い込んだら命がけ｜Once he makes up his mind, nothing can stop him.)

Comment: @Tim didn't notice that link... oh well, thanks.